# JavaScript (coffeeScript) prototype in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript, prototype

I am trying to build a javascript prototype functions in a given AngularJS project.
The javascript is coffee-script, but it is different to the script structures i know.
I get a syntax error: ( error: unexpected . after calc )

Here is a simple example of the structure of my class.

```
class MyClass extends Factory(„myApp.services“)
    constructor: () ->

    # some internal functions
        myVal = 100
        getMyVal = ->
            return myVal

        # functions used by other classes
        return {
        calc: ( inVal ) ->
            retVal = inVal + getMyVal
            return rBox

        ### this prototype construction didn’t work 
        # ( error: unexpected . after calc ) :
        calc.prototype =
            showValue: ->
                console.log( getMyVal )
            return
        calc
        ### 

        }
    controller: () ->
#
    link: (scope, element, attribute  ) ->
#
```

I trieb to convert a class factory form 
https://www.toptal.com/web/making-html5-canvas-based-game-with-angularjs-and-createjs 
( app/view1/uiClasses/sky.js ) but the structure is different:

```
uiClasses.factory 'Sky', [
  'loaderSvc'
  (loaderSvc) ->

    Sky = (obj) ->
     @sky = new (createjs.Shape)
     @sky.graphics.beginBitmapFill(loaderSvc.getResult('sky')).drawRect 0, 0, obj.width, obj.height
     return

    Sky.prototype =
      addToStage: (stage) ->
        stage.addChild @sky
        return
      removeFromStage: (stage) ->
        stage.removeChild @sky
        return
    Sky
]
```

Did someone know how the prototype syntax works with the code for "MyClass" ?

thank you

Comment: I think your `}` before the controller is unnecessary. Also you should make sure that your comments are not the last line of a block(as coffeescript returns the last line of a block) and if you do not want any return value, you have to put the `return` in the last line.

Comment: The   }   belongs to the  **return { **. A few spaces missing here. But this returns the ` calc: (inVal) -> ` function. This works.